# Используется ли ip-адрес в сети? Как узнать?

Tags: ip, lan

Бодрого всем дня или ночи!
Вопрос из системного администрирования сетей.
Как определить использовался ли ip-адрес в сети? Сеть на DHCP.
Цель: забрать в использование один ip-адрес, не создав конфликта адресов.
Так как конфликтный адрес может находится и на выключенном ПК.

---

Не забываем, что это hashcode - а не ответы майл ру - команду пинг не предлагать.

Comment: У вас  вопрос, прям как на "ответы mail.ru". У вас в заголовке "используется" а в теме "использовался", а вещи то разные.  Чего хотите то?

Comment: Какой DHCP сервер? ISC dhcpd, работающий в связке с bind, замечательно пишет в файл зоны кому какой адрес и на какой срок был выделен.

Answer (score 1):

Arping вам в помощь. Подробнее [тут](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arping)